# ASP.NET index in @Html.TextBoxfor

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Here is part of my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(count) track by $index">  
<select ng-model="genreDropDown" ng-options="genre.GenreName for genre in  genres      track by genre.GenreId"><option value="" label="Select genre"/></select> 
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Genres[0].GenreId, new { @Value = "{{genreDropDown.GenreId}}" }) </div>
```

`count` is integer,There can be several Genres in object, so i need several dropdownlists and several textboxes.

Is there any options? Like `x.Genres[{{count}}].GenreId`? Or i have to write
x.Genres[0].GenreId, x.Genres[1].GenreId, x.Genres[2].GenreId?

Comment: You can't mix Razor and Angular like this. The Razor is rendered on the server while the Angular code is resolved on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can iterate through the Model like this:

```
 @model MySolution.MyProject.MyModel 
 @for (int i = 0; i < MyModel.Genres; i++)     
 {  
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Genres[i].GenreId,
 new { @Value = "{{genreDropDown.GenreId}}" }) 
 }
```